# How to listen the values existing in the cells then add the reminder in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a table to input quarterly data.
[image: whiteboard]

In the table, Q1 means quarter one, Jan, Feb and March etc. The user has to input data by the end of the quarter by the current data. Say toady is 3/16/2022 so it is in Q1. Because user can be forgetting to input the data so I want to add the reminder on the top.

My thought is that when page loading, I search the values in cells. If they are null the add the reminder. Also in input event to detect the values in input elements.

But I am not sure if this the best way to do that. Should I use some of listen event to implement it?

Comment: Are you getting (or going to save) values from some api, db, local storage, cache? Or just keeping them in some var while the site is open?

Comment: I have api to save data to the database.